# How do I disable a script for a few seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

Can somebody show me how to disable this script for a few seconds once it collides with an object tag "bouncy object".

Here's the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class playermovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 15f;
    private Vector3 target;

    void Start () {

        target = transform.position;

    }

    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

            target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
            target.z = transform.position.z;

        }        

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }

}
```

Comment: what you mean by disable? Stop updating? or stop calling this:  `transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);`

Comment: um what I mean is to stop this script completely but only for a few seconds  maybe like 5-6 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Just add a bool to the script, like

```
bool StopForAWhile = false;

void Update(){
    if(StopForAWhile){
    //the inside of your update
    }
}
```

Then set this bool to true for however long you want and to false if your want it to move again.

Comment: Also, if you know how long you want to stop it for, you can create a function which will restart the script after the time has elapsed using `Invoke`.

`public void StopScript(float delay)
{
    StopForAWhile = true;
    Invoke("RestartScript", delay);
}

public void RestartScript()
{
    StopForAWhile = false;
}`